# web UI framework for my needs

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm currently working on a web project with aims to create a minimalist, NUI influenced UI, but I hate designing with HTML and CSS. I'd really love to populate the page with javascript and AJAX and generate a completely layout or templates in pure javascript with the least amount of CSS and HTML as possible. I aim to have very few images on the site, most visuals should be generated by CSS(rounded corners, gradients, etc).

I've dealt with handlebar.js, and some libraries that stack on top of handlebars.js but they aren't really providing me with a fast way to develop a minimal UI for my web service.

My application is not a single page application.

Any suggestions that would fit my needs?

Comment: Webdesigning is about HTML and CSS because browsers are. JavaScript manipulates the DOM which is... Bootstrap is already a copy-paste way of adding complex components to a page (and is far from *new*). Did you check jQuery UI or basis like PURE (Yahoo!)?

Comment: I guess I'm looking for a UI library to generate the HTML and DOM objects for me. Basically like a desktop UI toolkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap works great and might be flexible enough.

http://getbootstrap.com

Comment: I guess I'm looking to even further myself from HTML. Web design is a head ache, and I'm much more focused on developing the back-end.

Comment: Hmm sorry I couldn't be of more help :/

Comment: Thanks for the response anyway. It always nice to discover new technologies.